# Why "reinitialise the class variable" when there is only one copy of class variable that is shared between all instance of this particular class

Tags: java, class, class-variables, static-initialization

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of static initialisation blocks. I saw the code and statements below from Java tutorial oracle. My question is, why did the tutorial states:

> "the advantage of private static methods is that they can be reused later if you need to reinitialise the class variable"

when there is only one copy of class variable that is shared between all instance of this particular class?

```
class Whatever {
    public static varType myVar = initializeClassVariable();

    private static varType initializeClassVariable() {

        // initialization code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you want to reset the static variable to its initial value.
One example could be a global counter that you want to reset from time to time

```
class Whatever {

  private static int counter = getCountInit();

  public static resetCounter() {
    counter = getCountInit();
  }

  private static getCountInit() {
    return 0; // or some fancy computation
  }

}
```

Another example is testing: Imagine you have a test-case A that changes some static variable of a class and a test-case B that also uses the static variable. Without setting the static variable back to the initial value, the outcome of the tests would be different depending on the order in that they run.
(side note: That is one major reason why having global state (and a static variable is global state) is often a bad idea - at least in larger software projects.)

Answer (score 2):

static for variable word means it is shared among all of the instances of the class so for example if you have 
class SpaceShip and have static variable color = "blue";
and create alot of spaceships I mean instances of that class
and you then change color to "red"
then all spaceships will have red color ...

Answer (score 1):

Static objects can be accessible only by static methods. So in case if you want to reset a static object value we should use static method for that. Generally this will not be exposed to API users so its better to keep them private here.